# 2D array with 2D arrays on the diagonal

Tags: python-3.x, numpy, matrix, scipy

I have matrix

```
J_plus = 
    [[ 0.0609698  -0.00022921 -0.00022921 ... -0.00022921 -0.00022921
    -0.00022921]
    [-0.00022921  0.0609698  -0.00022921 ... -0.00022921 -0.00022921
    -0.00022921]
    [-0.00022921 -0.00022921  0.0609698  ... -0.00022921 -0.00022921
    -0.00022921]
    ...
    [-0.00022921 -0.00022921 -0.00022921 ...  0.0609698  -0.00022921
    -0.00022921]
    [-0.00022921 -0.00022921 -0.00022921 ... -0.00022921  0.0609698
    -0.00022921]
    [-0.00022921 -0.00022921 -0.00022921 ... -0.00022921 -0.00022921
     0.0609698 ]]
```

and

```
J_minus: 
    [[ 4.46319168e-02 -8.94427191e-05 -8.94427191e-05 ... -8.94427191e-05
     -8.94427191e-05 -8.94427191e-05]
     [-8.94427191e-05  4.46319168e-02 -8.94427191e-05 ... -8.94427191e-05
     -8.94427191e-05 -8.94427191e-05]
     [-8.94427191e-05 -8.94427191e-05  4.46319168e-02 ... -8.94427191e-05
     -8.94427191e-05 -8.94427191e-05]
     ...
     [-8.94427191e-05 -8.94427191e-05 -8.94427191e-05 ...  4.46319168e-02
     -8.94427191e-05 -8.94427191e-05]
     [-8.94427191e-05 -8.94427191e-05 -8.94427191e-05 ... -8.94427191e-05
     4.46319168e-02 -8.94427191e-05]
     [-8.94427191e-05 -8.94427191e-05 -8.94427191e-05 ... -8.94427191e-05
     -8.94427191e-05  4.46319168e-02]]
```

how can I create a matrix

```
J = [[J_plus   0];
    [0        J_minus]]
```

so the final matrix should be a 2X2 diagonal matrix with J_plus and J_minus as the diagonal elements like this

```
J = [ J_plus    0;
    0         J_minus]
```

in numpy?

Comment: You might use [np.block](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.block.html).

Comment: What's the result's `shape` and `dtype`?  What are you going to do with it?

Comment: Try to allocate a matrix of the shape you like and assign using slicing, e.g. `M[0, 0:-1] = J_plus`.

Comment: https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/arrays.indexing.html

Comment: yes @desertnaut, since this equation was from a Machine learning paper by mistake I put the tag of Machine learning.

Comment: For the future, just keep in mind that tags are about the content of the question, not its context.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest way: [`scipy.linalg.block_diag`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.14.0/reference/generated/scipy.linalg.block_diag.html):

```
linalg.block_diag(J_plus, J_minus)
```

For a numpy based approach, we could use [`np.block`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.block.html). Though this is definitely not the way to go when it comes to stacking multiple arrays:

```
px, py = J_plus.shape
mx, my = J_minus.shape

np.block([[J_plus,              np.zeros((px, my))], 
          [np.zeros((py, mx)),  J_minus]])
```

---

For instance:

```
a = np.arange(16).reshape(4,4)
b = np.arange(24).reshape(4,6)

linalg.block_diag(a, b)

array([[ 0.,  1.,  2.,  3.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.],
       [ 4.,  5.,  6.,  7.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.],
       [ 8.,  9., 10., 11.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.],
       [12., 13., 14., 15.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.],
       [ 0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  1.,  2.,  3.,  4.,  5.],
       [ 0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  6.,  7.,  8.,  9., 10., 11.],
       [ 0.,  0.,  0.,  0., 12., 13., 14., 15., 16., 17.],
       [ 0.,  0.,  0.,  0., 18., 19., 20., 21., 22., 23.]])
```